# What kind of event does Cognito send from Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have created a `PreSignup` Lambda function to be used with Cognito Pre-SignUp trigger with the following code:

```
import { APIGatewayEventDefaultAuthorizerContext, APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';

export async function PreSignup(event: any, context: APIGatewayEventDefaultAuthorizerContext,) {
  console.log("...event:", event);
  console.log("...context:", context);

  let userName = event.userName;
  let email = event.request.userAttributes.email;

  console.log("...userName:", userName);
  console.log("...email:", email);

  // Confirming the event so Cogntio doesnt resend it again:
  event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
  event.response.autoVerifyPhone = true;
  event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
  return event;
}
```

Instead of setting up the `event` to `any` with `function PreSignup(event: any)` I would rather specify a type of the event.

I tried to specify it as `APIGatewayProxyEvent` like so:

```
function PreSignup(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: APIGatewayEventDefaultAuthorizerContext,) {...}
```

but it doesn't work as the `event` sent by Cognito Pre Sign-Up trigger is not a `APIGatewayProxyEvent` type. What kind of event is it?

## Edited later:

Below is copy/pasted event that was pushed by Cognito PreSignUp Trigger:

```
{
  version: '1',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  userPoolId: 'us-east-1_abcdef',
  userName: 'emailf@address.com',
  callerContext: {
    awsSdkVersion: 'aws-sdk-nodejs-2.799.0',
    clientId: 'CLIENT_ID_NOT_APPLICABLE'
  },
  triggerSource: 'PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser',
  request: {
    userAttributes: { email: 'emailf@address.com' },
    validationData: null
  },
  response: {
    autoConfirmUser: false,
    autoVerifyEmail: false,
    autoVerifyPhone: false
  }
}
```

Below is an example of another AWS event this time pushed by `AWS EventBridge` (similar to the one pushed by Cognito Trigger):

```
{
  version: '0',
  id: '0ee136cb-ea53-f9e0-a6a9-232dfb78b7d0',
  'detail-type': 'UserCreated',
  source: 'my.company.endpointname',
  account: '123456789012',
  time: '2021-01-29T03:05:54Z',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  resources: [],
  detail: { foo: 'bar', createdAt: 1611889553709 }
}
```

Comment: You can find our by printing the event any, as you are are already doing. So just need to trigger that event and check the console/logs for json of that event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PreSignUp_SignUp`: Your standard Cognito pool (username/password) signup

`PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser`: When a user is created using the admin method (to be clear, not when your creating an admin, but when you are an admin creating a different user).

`PreSignUp_ExternalProvider`: If you have third party signup, like Google or facebook

```
{
   "version":"1",
   "region":"us-east-1",
   "userPoolId":"us-east-1_xxxxxxx",
   "userName":"2d4eb80f-7998-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
   "callerContext":{
      "awsSdkVersion":"aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
      "clientId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   },
   "triggerSource":"PreSignUp_SignUp",
   "request":{
      "userAttributes":{
         "email":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
      },
      "validationData":null
   },
   "response":{
      "autoConfirmUser":false,
      "autoVerifyEmail":false,
      "autoVerifyPhone":false
   }
}
```

- 

```
{
   "version":"1",
   "region":"us-east-1",
   "userPoolId":"us-east-1_xxxxxxxxxxx",
   "userName":"efce8c11-e0ff-4400-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
   "callerContext":{
      "awsSdkVersion":"aws-sdk-java-1.11.856",
      "clientId":"CLIENT_ID_NOT_APPLICABLE"
   },
   "triggerSource":"PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser",
   "request":{
      "userAttributes":{
         "email_verified":"true",
         "email":"xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com"
      },
      "validationData":null
   },
   "response":{
      "autoConfirmUser":false,
      "autoVerifyEmail":false,
      "autoVerifyPhone":false
   }
}
```

- 

```
{
   "version":"1",
   "region":"us-east-1",
   "userPoolId":"us-east-1_xxxxxx",
   "userName":"Google_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "callerContext":{
      "awsSdkVersion":"aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
      "clientId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   },
   "triggerSource":"PreSignUp_ExternalProvider",
   "request":{
      "userAttributes":{
         "email_verified":"false",
         "cognito:email_alias":"",
         "cognito:phone_number_alias":"",
         "email":"xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com"
      },
      "validationData":{
         
      }
   },
   "response":{
      "autoConfirmUser":false,
      "autoVerifyEmail":false,
      "autoVerifyPhone":false
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why they would not include some example payloads for each use-case in the official docs.

Comment: I know.... why wouldn't they?! blows my mind. Also OP is the real MVP for posting these.

Answer (score 3):

> What kind of event is it?

It is a `PreSignUpTriggerEvent`. You can import it from `"aws-lambda"`.

If you also want to set the correct type of the `context` and `callback` objects automatically, you can instead set the type of the whole handler function to `PreSignUpTriggerHandler` and all of the arguments would have the appropriate types.

Example:

```js
import {PreSignUpTriggerHandler} from "aws-lambda";

export const handler: PreSignUpTriggerHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   // code
}
```

- `event` is of type `PreSignUpTriggerEvent`
- `context` is of type `Context`
- `callback` is of type `Callback<any>`

Another example:

```js
import {PreSignUpTriggerEvent, Context, Callback} from "aws-lambda";

export const handler = async (event: PreSignUpTriggerEvent, context: Context, callback: Callback<any>) => {
   // code
}
```